# Does chutzpah support requirejs shims/config?

Tags: requirejs, qunit, chutzpah

I have some qunit tests setup to test my code that extensively uses requirejs. I use Chutzpah to perform the test running within VS. Everything works fine if I run the tests in the browser but not from within VS only. It seems to be ignoring my require.config call. If I change my references in my files to not point to shims but directly to files, it will work, but that breaks other things within my code.

Does anyone have this working? If so, how? I have looked at their example code but it doesn't use require.config and shims.

Comment: Can you provide a repro of what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Start from [this tutorial](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/running-requirejs-unit-tests).

To run a config, with shims, just add a reference to your config file in chutzpah.json. Example below, slightly simplified for readability.

The chutzpah.json file

```
{
  "Framework": "qunit",
  "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
  "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
  "References": [
    { "Path": "../Scripts/Components/RequireJS/require.js" },
    { "Path": "config.js" }
  ]
}
```

The config.js file

```
require.config({
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4",
        "jquery-linq": "../Scripts/jquery.linq",
        "signalr": "../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0",
        "signalrhubs": "../Scripts/mock-signalr-hubs",
        "knockout": "../Scripts/knockout-3.3.0",
        "constants": "../Scripts/constants",
        "HomeVm": "Source/HomeVm"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.linq": {
            "deps": ["jquery"]
        },
        "bootstrap": {
            "deps": ["jquery"]
        },
        "signalr": {
            "deps": ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```